# Creating tables by filling in a template on excel

Tags: excel

I've got an excel spreadsheet of blood test parameters (column on right shows the parameter name, and on the left is the normal range).

Is there any way that I can fill in various values within the middle row of this table and apply a function that generates a new table containing parameter names, the values i inputted and normal ranges, whilst omitting the intervening rows in which the middle cell was left empty?

Your help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: So the same as the picture you've posted, but filtered so the rows with a blank in the middle column are removed?

Comment: Yep! but I want to keep that template table in place, and have the filtered table appear in separate cells to the side if that makes sense.